# Fitch proof for a=b

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Good evening!

I have got a question about identities in Fitch.
Given: $a = b$

To prove: $b = a$

Is the identity in fitch bidirectional, so I can just replace both with both?
Or do I have to do something like this and if yes, is this legit?:

$a = b$

$a = a$      \ =-intro

$b = a$      \ =-Elim: 1

Thank you very much

Comment: How does your text define "$=$"?

Comment: It looks fine to me: to be a bit more explicit about it, if $\phi = (x = a)$, then $\phi[x := a]$ by equality intro, so $\phi[x := b]$ by equality elimination on the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

Yes, that is okay.   You do not need to substitute every occurance of the replaced term.
$$\fitch{[a, b]}{\fitch{~~1.~~a=b}{~~2.~~a=a\qquad{=}\mathsf {intro}\\~~3.~~b=a\qquad{=}\textsf{elim }2,1\quad\because~\color{red}a=a,a\color{red}=b\vdash \color{red}b=a}\\~~4.~~a=b\to b=a}$$